# Ubuntu Firefox snap leaves .xdp temp files when saving download to Virtualbox NTFS shared directory

Tags: firefox, snap

I have Ubuntu Mate 20.04 running in a Virtualbox VM on Windows 10. I have the snap version of Firefox 94.0.1 running in the VM.

If I download a file in Firefox to my home directory on the ext4 file system, it is saved correctly. If I download to a Virtualbox shared Windows folder, Firefox creates two ".xdp"-prefixed files, one of which is the desired download, and it creates the desired filename as a zero-length file.

ls of example file:

```
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf   27266674 Nov  6 05:08  .xdp_ews357apv3-all-v3.9.1.24_c1.9.51.bin.WZTFC1
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf          0 Nov  6 05:08  .xdp_ews357apv3-all-v3.9.1.24_c1.9.51.bin.QHVOC1
-rwxrwx--- 1 root vboxsf          0 Nov  6 05:08  ews357apv3-all-v3.9.1.24_c1.9.51.bin
```

dir of example file:

```
11/06/2021  05:08 AM                 0 ews357apv3-all-v3.9.1.24_c1.9.51.bin
11/06/2021  05:08 AM                 0 .xdp_ews357apv3-all-v3.9.1.24_c1.9.51.bin.QHVOC1
11/06/2021  05:08 AM        27,266,674 .xdp_ews357apv3-all-v3.9.1.24_c1.9.51.bin.WZTFC1
11/06/2021  05:08 AM    <DIR>          .
11/06/2021  05:08 AM    <DIR>          ..
```

Chromium snap saves the file correctly, but I prefer using Firefox since I'm a heavy tab user.

The shared windows folder is mounted as:

```
driversAndInstallers on /media/sf_driversAndInstallers type vboxsf (rw,nodev,relatime,iocharset=utf8,uid=0,gid=998,dmode=0770,fmode=0770,tag=VBoxAutomounter)
```

`snap connections firefox` shows:

```
removable-media           firefox:removable-media         :removable-media
```

If I save to ~Downloads there is no problem, the extra files are not created.

Any suggestions on how I might fix this? Currently, I either download to home and then move to the shared folder with the file manager, or download to the shared folder and rename the files in Windows. These work, but are extra steps.